# Question regarding keylogger references

Tags: keyloggers

For educational purposes I would like to learn how keyloggers have been made so far... from the simplest to most complex keyloggers. I can't seem to find a book focusing on them, most of the books I've seen go through the whole arsenal of exploitation.

Comment: This is a very broad question. We can talk about a specific keylogger, but not the entire scope of all keyloggers.

Answer (score 1):

The most important things about keyloggers to consider:

- on what platforms (including what Windows version) do you need it to work?
- should it work in stealth mode (be invisible in Task Manager etc.)?
- how it should be installed on monitored system?
- what information except raw keystrokes do you need to capture? eg. screenshots, window names etc.
- how it should send you recorded data? online/offline, how often, how to avoid filling user's disk etc.
- if it should work in stealth mode, how to prevent forensics? what actions should be taken except deleting all files? how to trigger it remotely or automatically, when suspicious activity is spotted?

After you collect answers for these questions, you can start googling for specific solutions.

In the meantime, this is the source code of simple, non-stealth keylogger working on Windows 7 and later, for the reference:

http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40755-good-keylogger/